# How can I obtain random numbers in gekko?

Tags: python, random, numbers, gekko

I am trying to solve an optimization problem in Python, using gekko, where one of the variables takes on a random value at each time step, but I haven't been able to use the gekko function that returns random numbers.

Following the documentation page (http://t-t.dk/gekko/docs/user-manual/functions.htm), the function rnorm returns "a random number from a normal distribution with mean and variance provided". I used it as shown here:

```
x = m.Var(value=0)
m.Equation(x == 5.*m.rnorm(0, 1))
```

provided that

```
m = GEKKO()
```

but I get the following error message:

> AttributeError: 'GEKKO' object has no attribute 'rnorm'

I would like to know if there is something that I am missing or if there is another way to get random numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation link that you provided is to different gekko software:

> Gekko Timeseries and Modeling Software is a free and open-source software system for managing and analyzing timeseries data, and for solving and analyzing large-scale economic models. See the Gekko homepage: [www.t-t.dk/gekko](http://www.t-t.dk/gekko). Read more about the status of different Gekko versions on the Gekko versions overview page.

The Gekko Optimization Suite in Python `pip install gekko` is described in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gekko_(optimization_software)) and in the [Read the Docs documentation](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

> GEKKO is a Python package for machine learning and optimization of mixed-integer and differential algebraic equations. It is coupled with large-scale solvers for linear, quadratic, nonlinear, and mixed integer programming (LP, QP, NLP, MILP, MINLP). Modes of operation include parameter regression, data reconciliation, real-time optimization, dynamic simulation, and nonlinear predictive control. GEKKO is an object-oriented Python library to facilitate local execution of APMonitor.

Both software packages can analyze time-series data. The `numpy.random.randn()` function can be used with `gekko`.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
p = m.Param()
x = m.Var()
m.Equation(x==5*p)

for i in range(10):
    p.value = np.random.randn()
    m.solve(disp=False)
    print(x.value[0],p.value[0])
```

This solves the optimization problem 10 times with different values for `p` sampled from a normal, mean-zero distribution.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation page you linked is associated with another package that isn't the same as the Optimization Suite in Python. I suggest looking at this page: https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_methods.html for the correct documentation.

As for your question about random numbers, I suggest using another package like python's random or numpy's random.normal. I'm not sure how exactly to apply it in your problem without seeing more code; what you could do is have an array of random numbers for each timestep and multiply or add it in somewhere while writing the problem in Gekko.